# Getting Labels in JavaScript

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I'm expecting to see, `First Name requred` when the user have not entered but instead I'm getting "does not exsit" what I'm doing wrong here?

I have the following code that will alert user if the user have not entered or left blank the inputField:, I have tried with field_name, API_Name does not work.

```
 clickCreateCandidate : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('Create record');
    var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
    //getting the candidate information
    var candidate = component.get("v.candidate");

    //Validation
    if($A.util.isEmpty(candidate.First_Name__c) || $A.util.isUndefined(candidate.First_Name__c)){
        //Access Custom Label in Javascript 
        alert($A.get("$Label.c.First_Name")); //name of the field
    }
```

Field Definition detail:

```
Field Label First Name  
Object Name Candidate
Field Name  First_Name  
Data Type   Text
API Name    First_Name__c
```

[image]

Comment: The [$Label](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_dynamic.htm) global is for [custom labels](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm), which you can use to translate an application to multiple languages. While I don't have an answer to your question, I do know why you're not getting the results you expect.

Comment: You did answer to my question lol, I forgot to create custom labels (i know silly me but got excited working with lightning) please post this as answer.

Comment: I guess I outfoxed myself. Glad to know I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$Label](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_dynamic.htm) global is for [custom labels](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm), which you can use to translate an application to multiple languages. Make sure that the custom label has already been created.